# Delete rows of Dataframe based on dates in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame which has over 4000 columns and 3000 rows. Columns are companies and rows have daily stock closing price. The rows have daily observation data based on dates of the Month. Now, I want is to remove rows in between the  last date of of each month i.e. I want to have  data of only last day of month based on the avaiable date of month form my data frame. Last date of each month should be according to the date column in my data frame avaiable.
the main challenge and difference of my question to others is date of last month should be according to provided dates in my dataframe. Its a financial data and non trading days and no. of trading days differ from other types of sectors of industry
I illustrate some part of my dataframe.

```
Date        A   B
30/12/1999  1   3
04/01/2000  1   3
05/01/2000  1   3
06/01/2000  1   3
07/01/2000  1   3
10/01/2000  1   3
11/01/2000  1   3
12/01/2000  1   3
13/01/2000  1   3
14/01/2000  1   3
17/01/2000  1   3
18/01/2000  1   3
19/01/2000  1   3
20/01/2000  1   3
21/01/2000  1   3
24/01/2000  1   3
25/01/2000  1   3
26/01/2000  1   3
27/01/2000  1   3
28/01/2000  1   3
31/01/2000  1   3
01/02/2000  1   3
02/02/2000  1   3
03/02/2000  1   3
04/02/2000  1   3
07/02/2000  1   3
08/02/2000  1   3
09/02/2000  1   3
10/02/2000  1   3
11/02/2000  1   3
14/02/2000  1   3
15/02/2000  1   3
16/02/2000  1   3
17/02/2000  1   3
18/02/2000  1   3
21/02/2000  1   3
22/02/2000  1   3
23/02/2000  1   3
24/02/2000  1   3
25/02/2000  1   3
28/02/2000  1   3
29/02/2000  1   3
```

Desired output

```
Date        A   B
30/12/1999  1   3
31/01/2000  1   3
29/02/2000  1   3
```

I would really appreciate your help in this regard.

Comment: We have to assume that you searched thoroughly before asking. Please elaborate why [**these answers**](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%20%5br%5d%20last%20day%20month) were not helpful. "This question does not show any research effort" but is just plz send codez.

Comment: @Henrik the main challenge and difference of my question to others is date of last month should be according to provided dates in my dataframe. Its a financial data and non trading days and no. of trading days differ from other types of sectors of industry.

Comment: @Aquarius take a look at `lubridate` and `zoo` packages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `lubridate` and `dplyr`, first parse `Date`

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
df$Date <- dmy(df$Date)
```

Now we can build a `dplyr` chain to filter:

```
df %>% group_by(month = month(Date), year = year(Date)) %>%  filter(Date == max(Date))
```

where we `group_by` `month` and `year` columns we add, and then `filter` down to only the dates that are the `max` for each group. It returns

```
Source: local data frame [3 x 5]
Groups: month, year [3]

        Date     A     B month  year
      (time) (int) (int) (dbl) (dbl)
1 1999-12-30     1     3    12  1999
2 2000-01-31     1     3     1  2000
3 2000-02-29     1     3     2  2000
```

You could, of course, do this all in base R if you prefer.

**Edit:** H/T @Jaap for recommending using `group_by` to add columns instead of a separate `mutate`. You could also use `slice(which.max(Date))` instead of the `filter` term; it would likely be a hint faster, if that's a concern.

Comment: Thank you it works perfect just had to make `ymd`change thanks to @akrun which was my fault as I had not provided the similar date format, but it changes on itself when I write csv file.

Answer (score 2):

We can also use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)
setDT(df1)[, c('month', 'year', 'Date') :={tmp <- dmy(Date)
  list(month= month(tmp), year= year(tmp), Date= tmp)}
  ][, .SD[ which.max(Date)] ,.(month, year)]
#   month year       Date A B
#1:    12 1999 1999-12-30 1 3
#2:     1 2000 2000-01-31 1 3
#3:     2 2000 2000-02-29 1 3
```

Comment: actually my dataframe in r has date format as `1999-12-30` ,hence, I'm receiving error `Warning message:
All formats failed to parse. No formats found. `

Comment: @Aquarius If that is the case instead of `dmy` you should use `ymd(Date)` in the code

Comment: thank you! you have an idea what an problem child I am when it comes to R codes. Th answer no. 1 has quite easy code for someone like me to understand. Although I have made ymd change according to your help.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another possibility:

```
month_year <- as.numeric(as.factor(sub("^[0-9]*/","",df1$Date)))
df1[!!c(diff(month_year),1),]
#         Date A B 
#1  30/12/1999 1 3 
#21 31/01/2000 1 3 
#42 29/02/2000 1 3
```

This solution does not change the format of the date in the original dataframe. However, it is assumed that the data is chronologically ordered like the data displayed in the OP.

**data**

```
df1 <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(41L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 12L, 14L, 
16L, 17L, 18L, 22L, 24L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 32L, 34L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 
42L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 13L, 15L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 23L, 
25L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 33L, 35L, 39L, 40L), .Label = c("01/02/2000", 
"02/02/2000", "03/02/2000", "04/01/2000", "04/02/2000", "05/01/2000", 
"06/01/2000", "07/01/2000", "07/02/2000", "08/02/2000", "09/02/2000", 
"10/01/2000", "10/02/2000", "11/01/2000", "11/02/2000", "12/01/2000", 
"13/01/2000", "14/01/2000", "14/02/2000", "15/02/2000", "16/02/2000", 
"17/01/2000", "17/02/2000", "18/01/2000", "18/02/2000", "19/01/2000", 
"20/01/2000", "21/01/2000", "21/02/2000", "22/02/2000", "23/02/2000", 
"24/01/2000", "24/02/2000", "25/01/2000", "25/02/2000", "26/01/2000", 
"27/01/2000", "28/01/2000", "28/02/2000", "29/02/2000", "30/12/1999", 
"31/01/2000"), class = "factor"), A = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), B = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L
)), .Names = c("Date", "A", "B"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-42L))
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd create a vector containing the end of month dates for your data like so:

```
library(dplyr)
df.dates = seq(as.Date("1999-01-01"),as.Date(Sys.Date()),by="months")-1
df.dates = as.data.frame(df.dates)
names(df.dates) = "Date"
df.joined = inner_join(df.dates, df)
```

This assumes that you have your data in a data frame with the Date column named "Date"

*Re-reading the question, this won't work if the last trading day isn't the last day of the month. @alistaire has a better solution using max(Date)